# Agenda view of the current buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

EDIT: The solution was simple but "bonus points" for anyone that can explain why my method didn't work.

ORIG:
I would like an org-mode-custom-command to display an agenda which is only made from the current buffer.

The following snippet shows the kind of view that I want.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("b" "Buffer summary"
     ((todo "TODO" ((org-agenda-files '("~/.agenda/notes.org"))))))))
```

But, I don't want to specify a filename, rather I want to use the current buffer. Here is my stab at it.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("b" "Buffer summary"
     ((todo "TODO" ((org-agenda-files (buffer-file-name))))))))
```

When I open an org-buffer and run this agenda command the result is just a pretty much blank agenda view. I presume it's because buffer-file-name is being evaluated at point later than when I press the agenda view...?

I'm still beginning to learn elisp, so don't hesitate to point out the obvious. Thank-you.

EDIT:

Following a suggestion in the comments.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("b" "Buffer summary"
     ((todo "TODO" ((org-agenda-files (list (buffer-file-name)))))))))
```

I receive a backtrace.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  file-directory-p(nil)
...etc...
```

Comment: Untested guess: try `(list (buffer-file-name))` instead of just `(buffer-file-name)`, since the value should be a list. (It can be a single file name, but that has a different meaning; see the docstring for `org-agenda-files`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me, the most obvious is NOT to create an extra agenda view, and simply call any existing view on that buffer only (limit the view to the current buffer with a call such as `C-c a < a`, where `<` limits on the current buffer).

If you still want to make an extra agenda view for the current buffer, I'm not sure whether that's possible with all commands. For sure, calling `occur-tree` will work on the current buffer. Not sure about `todo` and the like.

Answer (score -1):

...The agenda view usually shows the information collected from all the agenda files  [For more info](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-files.html), first make sure that file you are trying to make agenda-viwable or trackable, by activating it via an org command `C-c [     (org-agenda-file-to-front)`

you can test the current buffe name by 
`(message (buffer-file-name))`

Normally, I use my agenda view from various files, but I can track different agendas e.g done, on-progress, fixed, bug, just by using hot-keys
Here is mine:

`(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(
    ("x" agenda)
    ("y" agenda*)
    ("o" todo "ONPROGRESS")
    ("n" tags-todo "+TIPS")
    ("d" todo "DONE")
    ("p" todo "PENDING")
        ("b" todo "BUG")
    ("f" todo "FIXED")
    ;("F" todo-tree "FIXED")
    ))`

So if I want to view e.g done stuffs `C-c a d`  this will show me all done lists regardless of which file they came.

Comment: How does this answer the question which I asked? Please re-read the question.

Comment: ...You downvoted already, that was quick!, My point is agendas might come from various sources(.org files),  why don't you use something like registers to open respective agenda files.?

Comment: I do use various org files. I load them like this (setq org-agenda-files
     (append
      (file-expand-wildcards "~/.agenda/*.org")
      (file-expand-wildcards "~/.agenda/**/*.org")))))
`. Those files change over time and I don't want to use registers to identify them.