# emacs > org mode > agenda - always use current buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using many different org mode files for various projects, and I rev them by adding the date to the filename eg filename-2020-09-17.org. I realize I could use version control but in this case that is not possible, due to needing to share the file with others who are not using VC.

I would like the Agenda to always show just the items for the current file/buffer.

When I save eg the file with filename-2020-09-16.org to filename-2020-09-17.org, then the agenda still shows the old file name unless I remove it from the agenda file list and add the new file.

I realize that I can use C-c a < a but I am lazy and would rather not have to type S-, each time to get the <.

I looked at
[Agenda view of the current buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495419/agenda-view-of-the-current-buffer)

And the OP says the solution was simple but he/she/they did not provide the solution - at least I don't see it and I tried the posted code but it no works.

I also found https://www.reddit.com/r/orgmode/comments/bxwovd/agenda_for_current_buffer/ but that did not seem to meet my need.

Specifically I would like to put something in .emacs so that this would apply to all files all the time.

I also looked into a keystroke macro programs  but this does not seem ideal.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple function to do what you want, but there is no error checking to make sure e.g. that you are invoking it from a buffer that is visiting an Org mode file. The idea is that you set the `org-agenda-files` list to contain just the file which the buffer is visiting and then you call the regular `org-agenda` function. Binding the modified function to the `C-c a` key may or may not be what you want to do, but you can try and decide for yourself:

```el
(defun org-agenda-current-buffer ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((org-agenda-files (list (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))))
      (org-agenda)))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c a") #'org-agenda-current-buffer)
```

Comment: Hi NickD, Thanks very much for taking the time and interest to help. I tried the code and I get an error "Symbol's function definition is void: buffer-filename". I am sure it is a minor thing but if you could help me resolve this, it would be much appreciated. Sorry, I am new to emacs and lisp and just dont know much.....

Comment: Misspelling: `buffer-file-name` - I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Hi NickD, I found this works for the Agenda, and also I think the Global list. But I found if I filter the Global list using "Press ‘N r’ (e.g. ‘0 r’) to search again: (0)[ALL] (1)TODO (2)DONE etc" then this does not work - the list is empty. I found I still need to add the current file to the Agenda using C-c [ in order for this to work. Is there any code you code add to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: That's because filtering the global list happens in a different buffer (the agenda buffer) so the `(current-buffer)` call above does not return the same thing as before. And no, there is nothing I can do about that in the code above: it just creates a local `org-agenda-files` list and invokes `org-agenda` on that. The only other thing I can think of is to change the *global* `org-agenda-files` list: whenever you open a a new org-mode file, clean it out and set it to contain just the file you just opened. That's a different mechanism, so you might want to ask a new question about it.

Comment: Hi NickD thanks for explaining further and I appreciate all the help you have given me